# How to fill NA values in a pandas Data Frame with linear regression prediction using scikit learn in Python?

Tags: python

I have a data frame, for example:

[image]

I need to fill the NA values from Age with a linear model using sklearn.LinearRegression values.

It can be in a new column, let's say "Age_LM" or in the same one.

I already have the values from the linear regression model in a list. I just want to know the best way to replace those values on each NA of the Age column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out this solution:

```
X['Age_Pred'] = linear_model.predict(X.drop('Age', axis = 1))

X['Age_LM'] = np.where(X['Age']>0, X['Age'], X['Age_Pred'])
```

Comment: Predicting a person's attribute such as age, which is essentially the number of years since once was born, from other variables is not a good idea and should be avoided at all costs. Essentially, age is not and can not be a dependent variable. Moreover, in prediction models age and similar person attributes are used as predictives and estimating the predictive from other predictives is ussually not a good idea. If you also include the outcome variables in predicting the predictive, it is even a graver mistake.